# Qt application failed in Wayland ivi-shell

Tags: qt, wayland, qtwayland

I want to launch a Qt application in Wayland ivi-shell.

I tried

```
QT_WAYLAND_SHELL_INTEGRATION=ivi-shell ./hello-qt-quick2 -platform wayland
```

Expect the Qt application could launch in Wayland ivi-shell.

But failed with the following message

```
Failed to load shell integration ivi-shell
```

Anybody knows what to do with it? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

That output is usually what you get when you try to run on a compositor that doesn't support the `ivi_application` extension.

If you run the application with `WAYLAND_DEBUG=1` set in the environment, there should be a line similar to this:

```
[3318761.478] wl_registry@26.global(19, "ivi_application", 1)
```

and one that binds to that interface:

```
[3318761.541]  -> wl_registry@26.bind(19, "ivi_application", 1, new id [unknown]@29)
```

If it's not there, then your compositor doesn't support the `ivi-shell` shell integration.

Answer (score 0):

I got some worked thing on Raspberry Pi 3 like this:

1. Set environment variable

   export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$HOME/.xdg
2. Run Qt5WaylandCompositor

   $ QT_WAYLAND_CLIENT_BUFFER_INTEGRATION=brcm ./ivi-compositor &
3. Run Qt5 client application

   $ QT_WAYLAND_SHELL_INTEGRATION=ivi-shell ./untitled2 -platform wayland

Comment: Please note that QT_WAYLAND_CLIENT_BUFFER_INTEGRATION=brcm should not be needed unless you have a broadcom gpu (like the raspberry pi)